# Error came when trying to upload image file to server from android application

Tags: android, heroku, django-rest-framework

I am trying to upload an image file to a server from an Android application which I developed, but the response from the server was the following html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name=“viewport” content=“width=device-width,initial-scale=1”>
<meta charset=“utf-8”>
<title>Application error</title>
<style media=“screen”>
html,body,iframe{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
html,body{height:100%;
overflow:hidden;}
iframe{width:100%;
height:100%:
border:0;
}
</style>
</head>
</body>
<iframe src=“//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/application-error.html”>    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

The following code was written in android side for uploading:

```
final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/png");

RequestBody req = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                     .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                     .addFormDataPart("userId", "1")
                     .addFormDataPart("image",sourceFile.getName(), RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, sourceFile))
                     .addFormDataPart("landmark","xyx")
                     .addFormDataPart("location","234124351245sdfgsdfb")
                     .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
                     .url("https://cyc-new.herokuapp.com/uploads/img_upload/")
                     .post(req)
                     .header("Authorization",credentials)
                     .build();
```

Comment: It appears that your server is not responsive.  Have you tried hitting the server endpoint (cyc-new) outside of the Java code... like with a curl or javascript post?

Comment: @mrrogers I didn't tested with **curl** ,But I tested with **Python's Requests Library** and it was a success. Here is my Python code;  
``import requests``  
``from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth``  
``url = 'https://cyc-new.herokuapp.com/uploads/img_upload/'``  
``filess = {'image': open('a1.png', 'rb')}``  
``r = requests.post(url,data={'userID': 5, 'landmark': 'test1','location':'test2'},auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'admin'),files=filess)``

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a header in the request builder that specifies the content type of the data. For example,

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                 .url("https://cyc-new.herokuapp.com/uploads/img_upload/")
                 .post(req)
                 .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8")
                 .header("Authorization",credentials)
                 .build();
```

Comment: Have tried using header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8") ,but the response is same.